# Calculate the distance between the iPhone and a door, knowing their physical widths

Tags: iphone, ios, camera, distance

I have this scenario:

I know the physical (not only in pixel) size of the screen of the iPhone.

Also I know the width of a door.

Now, if I have the iPhone camera on (with UIImagePicker or whatever), and I am in the position where the width of the door fits perfectly in the width of the camera, and the iPhone stands perfectly vertical, is it possible to know the distance between the iPhone and the door?

Comment: I think I'd just measure it, but you're going to need the angle of the lens also. :)

Comment: check this  https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/sdk/ios it might be helpful

Comment: @Kalpesh AR plays only a part, the trick comes after detection of the object-which in this case is the door-the distance between the object and the iphone is required to be calculated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would depend on the camera specs which vary between devices. For this reason I would try to sample some data with a ruler - for instance take a 3' wide plank, align the edges perfectly and measure distance. Do this with varying widths on different devices and you'll have a formula per device (basic algebra)

Comment: First of all, thanks! But the fact that the door fits in the iPhone camera view is not an absolute data, do you mean? iPhone 4, 4S and 5 camera views could fit the door's width and being at different distances? If so, I think there is no solution actually... :(

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean. It depends on the lens focal distance.

Comment: You deserved an accepted answer check :) Thank you for your help!