# Calculate the distance between the iPhone and an object, knowing their physical widths (of the iPhone as well)

Tags: iphone, ios, geometry, distance

if you check this thread started from me ([Calculate the distance between the iPhone and a door, knowing their physical widths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17923923/calculate-the-distance-between-the-iphone-and-a-door-knowing-their-physical-wid)) I accepted an answer, that states, correctly, that if you do not know focal lens data of the camera of the iPhone, there is no easy way to calculate the distance between an iPhone and, let's say, a door, knowing its width.

I have to start another thread now asking:

I know the physical (not only in pixel) size of the screen of the iPhone (for iPhone 5 is 2.31 inches)

Also I know the width of a door.

Now, if I am in the position where the width of the door fits perfectly in the width of the iPhone itself (not of the camera), and the iPhone stands perfectly vertical, is it possible to know the distance between the iPhone and the door in that moment?

Thank you for your kind help!

Comment: How is this different from the last question? You need the size of the camera sensor and the focal length of the camera lens. The screen size of the phone is irrelevant.

Comment: Did you managed to do it? I am also looking for same...

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean that there is some outside image capturing device (be it a human eye or another camera) and the image capturing device, the phone, and the door are all in a line such that the phone appears to be the same width as the door.

In this case, you still need a) the distance between the image capturing device and the phone and b) the optical information (such as focal length) of the image capturing device. Just sit down with a pen and paper and draw out the geometry for a little bit and you'll see that.

Comment: Ok, let's forget the camera, let's turn off the iPhone!  There is some outside image capturing device (and this is a human eye beside the iPhone, that is in the same position of the iPhone ) and the door are all in a line such that the phone appears to be the same width as the door. You can see it as a coin and the sun, both the same dimension. What about the distance then?

Comment: Well it can't be in *the same position as the iPhone* because then the iPhone would either fill the entire field of vision or not be visible at all.

Put using your example, if you put a coin up to the sun at the coin and the sun are the same apparent size, you still have to know the optical characteristics of your eye (viewing angle is the most relevant, but that comes from focal length/index of refraction) and how far in front of your face you're holding the coin.

Comment: I should point out that Vish's answer would actually work, although it's away from the paradigm you originally suggested.

Answer (score 1):

This is going to involve a trigonometric calculation. I think you might have done R&D on Gyroscope, if not then surely you should refer it.

1) Find angle your phone is making with ground. Like when you point the device's camera to bottom of the object.

2) Now you are having one angle and you are making 90 degree with ground. So basically you are forming a right angled triangle. And you had just found one of your angle near your hand.[image]

3) You can approximate distance of your phone from surface to your hand. So you got one side of triangle and one angle. Thus you can find second side i.e distance between you and object.

Hope this helps. :)